# Use Angular ui-router State in Page Template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to use a state defined in ui-router's `$stateProvider` in the view?

For example my state looks like this:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('peoplelist', {
      template: '<people></people>',
  })
```

And my HTML like this:

```
<div class="header">
  <button ng-click="updateList()"></button>
</div>

<!-- peoplelist view to go here-->

<div class="footer">...</div>
```

I also have this in my controller, where I want `$state.go` to reload just the `peoplelist` state, instead of the whole page.

```
vm.updateList = function() {
  $state.go($state.current, {}, { reload: 'peoplelist' });
}
```

Is this at all possible in Angular?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a separate controller for peopleList state as and mention it in the state defination as:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('peoplelist', {
      template: '<people></people>',
      controller: 'peopleListController'
  })
```

And in your peopleListController you can do

```
$state.reload()
```

to just reload that state

Also, if you want to navigate to this state from another state, you can use $state.go as:

```
$state.go('peopleList')
```

It will only load peopleList controller as per your state defination.

You can also pass params to $state.go and them to your state defination.

You can access them using $stateParams in your controller.